# Name 'variable' is not defined after implementing 'global variable' inside the function

Tags: python

I am currently working on my first program on python, however, when I've encountered a problem concerning the scope of definition of my variables. Here is the problematic sample of my code :

```
def listen(topLeft, bottomRight):

    timeless = 0
    # The key combination to check
    COMBINATIONS = [
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='b')}
    ]

    # The currently active modifiers
    current = set()

    def execute():
        global topLeft,bottomRight,timeless
        print("Do Something")

        if timeless == 0:
            topLeft = mouse.position
            timeless += 1
        elif timeless == 1:
            bottomRight = mouse.position
            timeless += 1
        elif timeless >= 2:
            return False

    def on_press(key):
        global timeless
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.add(key)
            if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in              COMBINATIONS):
                execute()

    def on_release(key):
        if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
            current.remove(key)

    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as     listener:
        listener.join()
```

Basically, once the Listener calls `on_press`, `execute` is called. In order to pass the `timeless` variable, I use the `global` tag. However, once the program comes to executing the `execute` function, I receive the following error code : `NameError: name 'timeless' is not defined`. 
Any help would be appreciated, as I have tried pretty much everything I could

Comment: The `global timeless` statement has no effect on `execute`; it just makes assignment to `timeless` *in `on_press`* refer to the global, rather than a local, variable.

Comment: However, `timeless` is *not* a global; it's a local variable of the `listen` function. Fix your indentation so we get a clearer idea of how your code is actually structured.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to ask about problems _global_ variables. However, you will do yourself a favour if you never use them. Use other mechanisms for passing values around.

Comment: @chepner Fixed the indentation. I see where you're coming from, however, as `execute` is called everytime `on_press` is called, I cannot use a local variable, as it will re-declare it everytime (and it is the listener that calls `on_press`).

Comment: @zvone Which other mecanisms are you thinking of? Because currently, I am restricted by the fact that I am not "personnally" calling the function, but it is the listener that does so. Is my only way out "changing" the listener's implementation directly in the library?

Comment: @WKstraw Python 3 lets you declare a variable as `nonlocal`, which means it will look for the name in the dynamic call stack for a matching variable, rather than go straight to the global namespace.

Comment: @chepner Wow! Chnaging the `global` statement to `nonlocal` resolved my problem, somehow... I always thought that these two tags did the same thing. Do you want to answer the post so I can flag it as an answer?

Comment: (My previous comment erroneously refers to the call stack; my answer correctly refers to the containing lexical scope.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `timeless` is actually a local variable in the function `listen`, it's not a global variable, and in fact your error comes from the fact that there is no global variable named `timeless`. What `execute` needs is to declare `timeless` (and probably `topLeft` and `bottomRight` as well) as nonlocal, so that it refers to the first binding in the stack of containing lexical scopes.

```
def listen(topLeft, bottomRight):

    timeless = 0
    # The key combination to check
    COMBINATIONS = [
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='b')}
    ]

    # The currently active modifiers
    current = set()

    def execute():
        # modify the local variables in listen
        nonlocal topLeft,bottomRight,timeless
        print("Do Something")

        if timeless == 0:
            topLeft = mouse.position
            timeless += 1
        elif timeless == 1:
            bottomRight = mouse.position
            timeless += 1
        elif timeless >= 2:
            return False

    ...
```

In a function defined at the global scope, `global` and `nonlocal` are identical, as the first containing scope *is* the global scope. In a nested function, `global` jumps straight to the global scope, while `nonlocal` walks up the nesting scopes one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a global variable *outside* of any function. You can reference a global variable inside a function without using the keyword. You only need to use the keyword `global` when you are assigning a new value to the variable, sort of as a way of specifying that you want to assign the value to the global variable and not to a new local variable that shares the same name. [See this for examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/). For your example, first define your globals outside of any function, then use them in the functions, using the `global` keyword when you want to modify:

```
# Global variable definitions outside of any function.
timeless = 0
topLeft = 0
bottomRight = 0

# Define the function that uses the variables.
def execute():
    print("Do Something")
    global timeless
    if timeless == 0:
        global topLeft  # modifying the global variable with this name!
        topLeft = mouse.position
        timeless += 1
    elif timeless == 1:
        global bottomRight  # modifying the global variable!
        bottomRight = mouse.position
        timeless += 1
    elif timeless >= 2:
        return False
```

All of that said, it's probably best to avoid globals in general. You could define a class instead and use a member property for those things that need to be modified and referenced in multiple methods. For example, something like:

```
class Listener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeless = 0
        self.top_left = 0
        self.bottom_right = 0

    def execute(self, mouse):  # pass some mouse object in, otherwise what's "mouse"?
        print('Do something')
        if self.timeless == 0:
            self.top_left = mouse.position
            self.timeless += 1
        elif self.timeless == 1:
            ...
```

Comment: I also don't want to use global variables, however it is the only way I've found to make my function not re-declare `timeless` every time it is called. Concerning your code, I just tried it, and it now tells me : `name 'timeless' is used prior to global declaration`  (as the `if` is before the `global` tag i think)

Comment: Did you move the `timeless = 0` declaration outside of all functions?

Comment: Yes I did : i moved right underneath the `listen` definition. This error code popped up, so I moved it right underneath all the `import` tags : same problem

Comment: Huh, weird. Try it with `global timeless` before the `if` statements. I would still recommend converting everything to a class though and just use declare `self.timeless` etc. for your reused variables in the `__init__` method and use as needed in other defs in the class. I updated with an example of how to start that class.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! For now I will stick onto using `nonlocal` instead of global, as it, somehow, works. However, I will definitely try your method next time, as global variables are way too much of a struggle

Comment: @WKstraw take a look at my update for an example of how to start building that class.

Comment: Yes, I see. I didn't even think of building a class for a Listener. However this looks like way more simple and even solve some of my other, messily-solved, problems. Will test it out soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
timeless = 0
topLeft = 0
bottomRight = 0
current = set()

def listen(topLeft, bottomRight):
    timeless = 0
    # The key combination to check
    COMBINATIONS = [
        {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='b')}
    ]
    # The currently active modifiers
    current = set()

def execute():
    print("Do Something")
    if timeless == 0:
        topLeft = mouse.position
        timeless += 1
    elif timeless == 1:
        bottomRight = mouse.position
        timeless += 1
    elif timeless >= 2:
        return False


def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute()


def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)
```

Comment: You have to right your main function which starts execution in the last at same level not inside any function